# Как работает данная ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf

Немного не понимаю магию этого кода:

```
      public partial class MainWindow : Window, IModel
        {
            readonly ViewModel _viewModel = new ViewModel();
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                DataContext = _viewModel;
            }
          public void SetModel(string value)
        {
            _viewModel.SetModel(value);
            this.ShowDialog();
        }

    }

    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Model _model;
        public string ModelName
        {
            get { return _model.ModelName; }
            set
            {
                _model.ModelName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ModelName");
            }
        }
public void SetModel(string value){
_model=new Model(value)
}
     protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

      class Model
    {
        public string ModelName { get; set; }

        public Model(string name){
            ModelName=name
        }
    }
```

Почему при данной реализации, при создании типа Model, значение сразу же отображается с забинженном поле? Хотя  `OnPropertyChanged("ModelName");` не вызывался явно.

Comment: Еще вопрос, а при ShowDialog(), как я понимаю тоже считаются неявно свойства модели и отобразятся на форме?

Comment: Не понял что вы имеете ввиду

Comment: @АндрейNOP, я немного переборщил с минимальным примером и упустил несколько деталей. У меня перед показом формы вызывается метод _viewModel.SetModel(model), а дальше идет ShowDialog(). Т.е по факту, модель присваивается не в конструкторе.

Comment: Ну тогда показывайте как у вас там реально сделано. Не могу понять каким тут боком в VM ShowDialog

Comment: Подправил немного.

Comment: А кто у вас окно создает и вызывает `SetModel` на нем? В любом случае, вы можете поставить брейкпоинт в геттер свойства и посмотреть в какой момент он вызывается и есть ли в этот момент там значение.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, внешний компонент. Это некий расширитель-плагин.

Comment: Ага, судя по всему, применение стилей и привязок происходит уже после вызова `Show()/ShowDialog()`, когда все стили и привязки применены срабатывает событие `Loaded`

Comment: @АндрейNOP, дополните тогда свой ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все стили и привязки применяются после вызова метода `Show()/ShowDialog()` окна (в этот момент срабатывает событие `Loaded`, читайте комментарии [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.show(v=vs.110).aspx) и [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded(v=vs.110).aspx)), поэтому, когда фреймворк первый раз читает свойства VM, в них уже есть значения.

Если вы затем уже где-то смените значение

```
_model = new Model("XXX");
```

то WPF об этом, естественно, не узнает и не обновит представление.